# handle messages one by one in celery

Tags: celery

I have this configuration of celery in my launch.json (i am running it on linux docker):

```
{
    "name": "Python: Celery",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "celery",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "args": [
        "-A",
        "celery_worker",
        "worker",
        "-Q",
        "test pipeline *** collect BB",
        "--concurrency=1",
        "-l",
        "info",
        "-P",
        "solo",
    ]
},
```

I set "--concurrency=1" as mention in the documentation.

When for example I send 4 messages to my RabbitMq broker, activate the worker, puts breakpoint in the entry to the start of the function that handle the message, and then terminate the program before sending response back, I see that all 4 message are Nack in the RabbitMq and I expect only 1 message to be Nack

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the behavior that you want, you have to ensure that [two settings are set](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#reserve-one-task-at-a-time):

```
task_acks_late = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```